# Changing template using Pyramid, traversal and PyMongo

Tags: python, themes, pyramid, traversal, template-engine

If I wanted to achieve something like a WordPress template theme engine, how should I do it with Pyramid, traversal, and using MongoDB as the database.

I've tried looking it up on [Extending An Existing Pyramid Application](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/extending.html), but it doesn't make any sense at all...

---

Basically, in the admin control panel, when the owner goes to `www.mydomain.com/admin/template`, the page will display all the themes folder located in say /static/themes/.

When the admin selects the theme "mybluetheme", the theme will be stored in MongoDB. So, when I view it in `www.mydomain.com/`, it will be showing the theme using "mybluetheme".
If tomorrow, the admin selects "mygreentheme", the site will be rendering "mygreentheme".

Comment: It would help if you explain what you're trying to achieve in more details - not every Python developer is familiar with wordpress template theme engine. Also, how do traversal and mongodb fit into the picture? Do you want the theme identifier to be in the URL and to load the themes from mongodb?

Comment: Hi, I've added more details, and I'm using jinja2, not the default pyramid template. My thought would have been to change the @view_config(context='XXX', renderer='/static/themes/mybluetheme/index.jinja2')... However I can't seem to figure out a way to change the value in the renderer

Comment: I've updated my answer. The basic idea is that it may be much easier to override the base template which is used by multiple templates than trying to do tricks with `renderer` parameter of @view_config

Answer (score 3):

Not knowing anything about wordpress template theme engine, I'd like to show you how you can swap the base template depending on some criteria:

```
from pyramid.renderers import get_renderer
from pyramid.security import authenticated_userid

class Theme(object):

    def __init__(self, context, request):
        self.context = context
        self.request = request

    @property
    def layout(self):
        if utils.likes_blue_color(authenticated_userid(self.request)):
            template_name = 'templates/blue_layout.pt'
        else:
            template_name = 'templates/green_layout.pt'
        return get_renderer(template_name).implementation()

@view_config(...)
def index(context, request):

    theme = Theme(context, request)

    return { 'context':context,
             'request': request,
             'theme':theme,
           }
```

Layout template would look something like

```
<html ...
     metal:define-macro="master">
....
<metal:sidebar define-slot="sidebar">...</metal:sidebar>
<metal:body define-slot="main">...</metal:body>
</html>
```

And the rest of your templates will use that as follows:

```
<html ...
    metal:use-macro="theme.layout.macros['master']">

<metal:main fill-slot="main">
    Hi there!
</metal:main>
</html>
```

using this approach, you'll be able to swap the base template based on some parameter (value in the request, cookie, user setting in the database etc.)

With Jinja2 templates the approach would be similar - you figure out what *base template* you need in your view function and pass *a reference* to the base template object, or *the file name of the base template* to your function. From the [Jinja2 documentation](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#template-inheritance) it appears  that `{% extends my_base_template_passed_from_the_view_function %}` syntax might work. Otherwise you may need to specify a custom template loader to load a different template based on some condition.